# Highcharts polar chart - zero at centre

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I feel this must be easy but I'm just not seeing it. In the following, I want the 0 to be the very centre of the plot. 
http://bit.ly/1LE6Cvr

I presumed this could be achieved with the "min" option but it does not work as expected. Instead, the zero point is created at half the charts radius.

Can someone please put me out of my misery? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have found a solution myself.
It would seem only way to have to plot point sitting neatly at 0 is to have a "max" value. See [example](http://bit.ly/1PSTlDa).

But of course in most cases, you cannot just decide on an arbitrary max value if your series is being generated dynamically.

The trick is to determine from the API what the max value for the chart's yAxis dataset is, which if 0, you know there is no data to show, so you then set it dynamically.

See [solution](http://bit.ly/1Wla01a)

Comment: I will mark the above as the chosen solution as it best suits my needs, that is unless anything comes up with a favourable alternative in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the data your putting into the chart.

Because all of your plot points are 0 highcharts is adjusting the axis in order to make the data display in a readable manner.

If you adjust the data to a wider spread of numbers 0 becomes the center of the chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/3w8hq9tg/

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            polar: true
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
        },

        pane: {
            startAngle: 0,
            endAngle: 360
        },

        xAxis: {
            tickInterval: 45,
            min: 0,
            max: 360,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + '°';
                }
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointStart: 0,
                pointInterval: 45
            },
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Line',
            data: [10, 0, 1, 5, 1, 6, 6, 2]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear but the point is, I'm not sure what the data will be, and in my case the data values pulled for a particular time period could all legitimately be zero.

Comment: if all your data points for a time period could be zero maybe another chart type is better suited for your needs. a singular central dot on a radial chart isn't really insightful or engaging.

Comment: While the scenario would be very rare (zero values) it is possible and I don't find the highcharts default a desirable representation of such. Think of transactions during a 24 hour period. Maybe between 3am and 4am, there are none. Not unlikely and for me, not a reason to abandon a polar chart.